# Fork() printing multiple case in switch-case

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, switch-statement, fork

I just started to learn Linux programming,My doubt may seem very silly to you,but i am really very confused,so help me to get through this-
here goes the code

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "err.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a=-5;
    switch(a=fork()){
        case -1:
            cout<<"error\n";
            break;
        case 0:
            cout<<"here comes the child\n";
            break;
        default:            
            cout<<"a is "<<a<<endl;
//      break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:
a is 28866
here comes the child

- Question1:I don't understand why both case 0: and default: gets
  executed !
- Question2:According to me value of a should be 0 if child process is
  created successfully!

Comment: Did you carefully read (several times) the documentation of [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)? You should take several hours to read both. BTW, every case should end with `cout << endl` (not just `cout << "\n"`....) or `cout << flush`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question1:I don't understand why both case 0: and default: gets executed !

The case 0 is executed by the child process, where `fork` returns 0. The default case is executed in the parent process, where the return value of `fork` is the pid of the new child process.

Fork, as the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) says, creates an exact duplicate of the calling process, including the current instruction pointer. I.e. both, the parent, and the child process will execute the switch statement.

> Question2:According to me value of a should be 0 if child process is created successfully!

In the child process, yes. In the parent it's the child process's pid.

Answer (score 2):

On successful execution, the fork command returns the process id of the child process to the parent process and it returns 0 to the child process. After the fork command execution, both the parent and child process execute the same set of instructions. In this case, both the child and the parent processes execute the switch statement. The value "a is 28866" is printed by the child process and the value "here comes the child" is printed by the parent process. To make the parent and child processes execute different instructions, check the return value of the fork command.

Answer (score 1):

See the [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) documentation:

> ```
>    On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent,
>    and 0 is returned in the child.
> ```

So in your example, you get *both* `28866` and `0` as return values in two seperate processes (parent process and child process) which explains the output. Note that the output order could vary.

This is was `fork` was done for: You want to execute your program or parts of your program simultaneously. The return value allows you to detect which process you are in.

Comment: Not in two separate *threads* but in two separate *processes* (each having its *own* address space)